# PHP & MySQL - does UPDATE but not INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

hoping you can help.

I have a script which runs 2 parts. The top part either returns no rows, and if it does, an INSERT and UPDATE query is run.

The second part does the same thing, logic wise.

If the top part return no rows, the second part of the script works fine

BUT

if the top part return rows then in the second part of the script only the UPDATE query takes place but not the INSERT (and it does not give any errors)

What could be the issue? This is really beginning to bug me.

Here is the script

```
<?php

  require_once('function.sendtxt.php');

  $now = time();
  $received = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $now);

  mysql_connect("x", "x", "x") or die(mysql_error());
  //echo "Connected to MySQL<br />";
  mysql_select_db("x") or die(mysql_error());
  //echo "Connected to Database<br />";

  //$a = array();
  //$a[] = array("id=0", "text");
  $txt = 'We have cancelled your order as we have not heard back from you in a while. To order, please resend your request';

  // those orders not complete over 30 minutes
  $select = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, received, txtus, link, sender
    FROM incoming_texts
    WHERE id IN (
      SELECT i3.id FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT i2.link as link, max(i2.id) as id
        FROM incoming_texts i1
        JOIN incoming_texts i2 ON i1.id = i2.link
        WHERE (i1.link = 0)
        GROUP BY i2.link ASC
      ) i3
    )
    AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, received, now()) > 30
  ") or die(mysql_error());

  if (mysql_num_rows($select) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($select)) {
      // id, received, txtus, link, sender
      $id .= "," . $row["id"];
      $txtus = $row["txtus"];
      $link = $row["link"];
      $from = $row["sender"];
      //$received = $row["received"];

      //echo $id;

      // cancel the row
      mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO incoming_texts
          (txtus, sender, msg, received, this_step, next_step, link)
        VALUES
          (".$txtus.", ".$from.", 'cancel_inactive_text_orders.php 1', '".$received."', 'cancel', 'order', $link)
      ") or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      //sendtxt($txtus, $from, $txt);
    }
    // -2 = cancelled
    mysql_query("
      UPDATE incoming_texts
      SET link = -2
      WHERE link IN (00".$id.")
    ") or die(mysql_error());
  }


  /*
    below is the second part
  */

  $link0 = mysql_query("
    SELECT id, received, txtus, link, sender
    FROM incoming_texts
    WHERE (
      link = 0
      AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, received, now()) > 30
    )
  ") or die(mysql_error());

  if (mysql_num_rows($link0) > 0) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($link0)) {
      // id, received, txtus, link, sender
      $id = $row["id"];
      $txtus = $row["txtus"];
      $link = $id;
      $from = $row["sender"];
      //$received = $row["received"];

      $link0rows = mysql_query("
        SELECT id
        FROM incoming_texts
        WHERE link = ".$id."
        LIMIT 1
      ") or die(mysql_error());

      if (mysql_num_rows($link0rows) < 1) {
        mysql_query("
          UPDATE incoming_texts
          SET link = -2
          WHERE (id = $id)
        ") or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_query("
          INSERT INTO incoming_texts
            (txtus, sender, msg, received, this_step, next_step, link)
          VALUES
            (".$txtus.", ".$from.", 'cancel_inactive_text_orders.php 2', '".$received."', 'cancel', 'order', $id)
        ") or die(mysql_error());

        //echo $id . " ";
        //sendtxt($txtus, $from, $txt);

      } // if
    } // while
  } // if

  mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: `(and it does not give any errors)` - are you certain? Looks to me like `$link` in the query would be a string, so it should be `'$link'`...

Comment: $link is a number so it doesn't need the apostrophe, the thing is it does work, but not if there are rows returned by the first part of the script, and even then the UPDATE works but not the INSERT :(

Comment: @DaveRandom I've tried your version of the script and still no luck, btw its the bottom half of the script that stops working (when the first bit works)

Comment: @paddy I didn't change anything about it apart from the indentation for readability - maybe could try `echo`ing the queries that are produced and running them directly (e.g. in phpMyAdmin) to see what the result is?

Comment: I got it working! I switched the code, i.e. the top part at the bottom and the bottom bit at the top and its working! I don't know why, but at this moment I don't have the energy to figure out why, just happy that it works :S

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine except this one ... parameters `$txtus` and `$from` are not properly quoted

```
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO incoming_texts 
   (txtus, sender, msg, received, this_step, next_step, link) 
    VALUES ('".$txtus."', '".$from."', 'cancel_inactive_text_orders.php 
    1', '".$received."', 'cancel', 'order',$link) ") 
    or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
```

Comment: $link is a number so it doesn't need to be quoted

Comment: @paddy, edited post. Correct `$link` is not string type ... so no need of quoting but you haven't quoted the literal types as well. See my edit.

Comment: Oh, they are numbers aswell. But here's the thing, the query works, just not when the top bit returns some rows, and even then the UPDATE query works but not the insert, its like it misses it out altogether because it doesn't give any errors either!

Comment: I got it working!

I switched the code, i.e. the top part at the bottom and the bottom bit at the top and its working!

I don't know why, but at this moment I don't have the energy to figure out why, just happy that it works :S

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the queries into a variable first and printing them out so you know the query is actually correct.

I believe you are most likely missing quotes around some of the strings in the insert, such as $txtus and $from

Comment: The query is correct, it works just not when the top bit returns some rows, and even then the UPDATE query works but not the insert, its like it misses it out altogether because it doesn't give any errors either!